# text-orientation:upright is not supported in IE11

Tags: css, sass

the text-orientation:upright is not supported in IE11. do we have any other css property to display Text upright?
Eg:

S

T

A

R

T

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, including `writing-mode`, `text-orientation`, and `text-combine-horizontal`. For IE11 you will want to look at `text-combine-horizontal`

Consider [this](http://generatedcontent.org/post/60984978732/text-combine-horizontal) article.